# How to read .Contact files?

Tags: mobile, libraries, java

I will explain the situation first. We know we can send the contacts in our phone via bluetooth to other devices. Usually they will be sent as ".contact" files. In windows these files will be saved in c:/users/userName/contacts folder. In my Java program (which runs in PC), I would like to read these files. Is there any specific library to read these files? Specially libraries which are not outdated for decades? Please help!

Comment: What are these documents? Are they text files? Have you tried anything to read them like you would any other file on the filesystem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Sync Desktop application with the Phone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12060251/how-to-sync-desktop-application-with-the-phone)

Comment: It is for a phonebook software. "Windows Contacts" and some other read these and extract the data, so, these data must be in a specific format/way.

Comment: Can you post one of these so we can have a look?

Comment: @Jonatan: Post file? You mean .contact? No need, just turn on bluetooth in the laptop, and send the contact from your phone to your laptop via bluetooth. The format will be .Contact.. Oh, and another thing, in phone it will be "send name card" or something similar

Comment: @trashgod: There is a big different between "sync" and manually sending and adding files.

Comment: I don't have access to a Windows machine. Do the files look like this? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Contacts#Example_Windows_Contact_file. If so, you could use any XML parser, perhaps write queries using XPath.

Comment: hey hey hold on..Is this is platform specific? I don't think so???

Comment: Well, I don't know the contents of your file, but if the file structure matches that of the link I posted, then the format is Microsoft specific. Perhaps your phone sends a vCard (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard), which is then converted to a .contact? If you need this to work on several platforms, I think you should stay away from .contact.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Jonathan. OK, I believe phones are not built to send platform specific contact files. So, you must be right! My phone might have sent a vCard, and it got converted to .contact :(. How to find it??

Comment: There is a java library called bluecove (http://bluecove.org/) which allows you to send and receive bluetooth messages, perhaps this can help?

Comment: Hi Jonathan. I tried to send the contact as a text message, and the subject displayed as "namOfThePerson.vcf". Hey this is vCard isn't it? So, why windows converted it ? THanks for the bluetooth library too.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, please provide your above suggestions and "stay away from .contact" suggestion as an answer. I will mark it as the answer

Comment: @Jonatan: Hi, please provide the mentioned comment as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, rephrasing comments as an answer, as requested.

The .contact file you're seeing is most likely Microsoft specific, and you should look for some other format, such as vCard instead! You might also find the bluetooth software at [bluecove.org](http://bluecove.org) interesting.